# How do I change the subject of each of my cron jobs?

Tags: cron

This my crontab file:

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
MAILTO=richardheyes@gmail.com

0 0 * * * ./backup.sh
0 8,12,16,20 * * *  /bin/bash /kunden/homepages/46/d548322256/htdocs/dev/admin/sitemaps/create.sh
0 8,12,16,20 * * *  `which php7.1` -q /kunden/homepages/46/d548322256/htdocs/dev/admin/sitemap-html/create.php
```

As you can see there's a backup shell script, a shell script creates a plain text sitemap file and a PHP command-line script that creates a HTML sitemap.

The resulting sitemaps are viewable here:

https://www.rgraph.net/sitemap.txt

https://www.rgraph.net/sitemap.html

The resulting emails from the cron tasks come through to me as intended but with a subject line like this:

```
Cron <u78819167@infongp-uk31> `which php7.1` -q /kunden/homepages/46/d548322256/htdocs/dev/admin/sitemap-html/create.php
Cron <u78819167@infongp-uk31> ./backup.sh
```

Which is just plain ugly. Now I could prevent the email by ensuring the tasks don't produce any output or redirecting the output to /dev/null - but if any errors crop up I'd like to see it.

So my question is:

How can I change these butt ugly subjects to something that looks nicer, on a per cron job basis? Is there an environment variable that I can set from each script that would be used as the subject?

Comment: look at https://serverfault.com/questions/56497/how-to-modify-a-cronjob-email-subject for several different approaches.  (google is your friend)

Comment: Thank you for the link. I did search - but using the stack overflow search - not Google.